# CMake: download and run msi

Tags: windows, cmake

Using kitware's CMake, is it possible to automatically download a Microsoft installer (MSI) file and execute it (on Windows, of course)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It generally should be.  However, clearly running the installer will block the CMake process until the user completes all the required inputs to the installer.

Here's an example for 7-zip's installer making use of [`file(DOWNLOAD ...)`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command%3afile) and [`execute_process`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command%3aexecute_process):

```
set(DownloadedMsi ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/7z920-x64.msi)

file(DOWNLOAD http://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/files/7-Zip/9.20/7z920-x64.msi/download
     ${DownloadedMsi}
     TIMEOUT 30
     STATUS StatusVar
     LOG LogVar
     EXPECTED_HASH SHA1=4173fea2af9a595fa0be1ef8251f412229687be1)

message("\${StatusVar} - ${StatusVar}")
message("\${LogVar} - ${LogVar}\n\n\n")

execute_process(COMMAND cmd /c "${DownloadedMsi}"
                RESULT_VARIABLE ResultVar
                OUTPUT_VARIABLE OutputVar
                ERROR_VARIABLE ErrorVar)

message("\${ResultVar} - ${ResultVar}")
message("\${OutputVar} - ${OutputVar}")
message("\${ErrorVar} - ${ErrorVar}")
```

Comment: Thanks. Would probably be better to run "MsiExec" instead of cmd but in the end I found it more straightfoward just to put the appropriate dlls and libs in our source code control system and extract them from there.